# How to assign a shortcut key to run a particular EASE script

Tags: eclipse, scripting, keyboard-shortcuts

I am curious whether it is possible to assign a shortcut key to run a particular EASE script. I know that I can [add scripts to UI](http://codeandme.blogspot.ru/2014/12/ease-scripts-conquer-ui.html), but for me applying of shortcut keys is more familiar and convenient way to do my work.

Maybe, first I should create a popup-menu item and then assign a key to the item. So I've added [the context menu item](http://codeandme.blogspot.ru/2014/12/ease-scripts-conquer-ui.html) but I can not find any reference to the item in **Preferences>>General>>Keys**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out the way to run a particular EASE script typing a sequence of keys:

1. create an eclipse plugin project;
2. add extension points to define a key binding, a command handler and an ease module;
3. write a module class and a command handler class.

The command handler's method called "execute" is invoked when I type the sequence of keys. As I can use the module to access the command handler synchronously, so I can assign code to be run from within the "execute" method.

This is **plugin.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>
   <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.bindings">
        <key sequence="Ctrl+Shift+D"
            commandId="m5.command_0"
            schemeId="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration"
            contextId="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.javaEditorScope"/>
   </extension>
   <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
        <command name="Execute custom command"
            defaultHandler="m5.handlers.CustomHandler_0"
            description="Execute custom command"
            categoryId="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.category.source"
            id="m5.command_0">
       </command>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ease.modules">
      <module
            category="org.eclipse.ease.category.system"
            class="m5.handlers.Module1"
            id="M5.module1"
            name="M5.module1"
            visible="true">
      </module>
   </extension>
</plugin>
```

This is **the command handler**:

```
package m5.handlers;

import org.eclipse.core.commands.AbstractHandler;
import org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionEvent;
import org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionException;

public class CustomHandler_0 extends AbstractHandler {

    private static Runnable runnable;

    protected synchronized static void setRunnableToExecute(Runnable codeToRun){
        runnable = codeToRun;
    }

    @Override
    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent arg0) throws ExecutionException {
        System.out.println("command_0");
        if(runnable != null){
            runnable.run();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

This is **the module**:

```
package m5.handlers;

import org.eclipse.ease.modules.AbstractScriptModule;
import org.eclipse.ease.modules.WrapToScript;

import m5.handlers.CustomHandler_0;

public class Module1 extends AbstractScriptModule{

    @WrapToScript
    public void setCommand_0(String code){
        CustomHandler_0.setRunnableToExecute(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                getScriptEngine().executeAsync(code);
            }
        });
    }
}
```